# Pandas replace multiple values in repetition

Tags: pandas

I am trying to replace multiple values in a row to a single value.In the below output,if any row has atleast one 'YES' then it should replaced by 'YES' and if all values in a row are 'NO' then it should be replaced by 'NO'.

```
bcc_new.DOCUMENT_SUBMITTED.value_counts()

Output:

NO, YES, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO       212036
NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO         29549
NO, NO, NO, NO, YES, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO        26975
NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, YES, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO        23588
NO, NO, NO, YES, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO         4643
NO, YES, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, YES, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO        2580
NO, YES, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, YES, NO, NO, NO        1826
NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, YES, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO         1151
NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, YES, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO         1141
NO, YES, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, YES, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO         648

Expected output:
YES  212036
NO   29549
YES  26975
YES  23588
```

I tried this query but it is not working.Need help!!

```
bcc_new.loc[bcc_new['DOCUMENT_SUBMITTED'].isin(['YES']).any()]='YES'
bcc_new.loc[bcc_new['DOCUMENT_SUBMITTED'].isin(['NO']).all()]='NO'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `bcc_new['DOCUMENT_SUBMITTED']` is probably an object column, so you could do first:

```
o = bcc_new['DOCUMENT_SUBMITTED']
is_yes = (o.str.split(',\s+', expand=True) == 'YES').any(axis=1)
is_yes.value_counts()
```

this would give you your values with True and False as keys, but you could map them afterwards to Yes and No

#### EDIT

if you want to map the values to 'YES' or 'NO' you cound do:

```
counts = is_yes.value_counts()
counts.index = counts.index.map({True: 'YES', False: 'NO'})
```

Comment: how can i replace all repeated values into YES and NO ??